# How to show user profle edit tab as a default tab on user profile page?

Tags: users, hooks

I want to show user profile edit tab as a default, on page load its content must show. Like we have option in quick tab module, in which you can select which tab must show on page load.

How to perform this?

Comment: On which event you want to show user profile edit tab?

Comment: http://localhost/mgt/user.....when we write this url in address bar user must redirect to http://localhost/mgt/user/1/edit

Comment: Please follow the answer given by @lukedekker

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module to redirect users from /user/* to /user/*/edit. This could cause problems when other users are trying to view other user's profiles.

You can also do this with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). This would allow you to redirect users conditionally.